# Skipping Code in Swift 2.2

Tags: swift, if-statement

```
        if one != "a" {
        lOne.text = "G"
    }
    if one != "b" {
        lOne.text = "H"
    }
    if one != "c" {
        lOne.text = "I"
    }
    if one != "d" {
        lOne.text = "J"
    }
    if one != "e" {
        lOne.text = "K"
    }
    if one != "f" {
        lOne.text = "L"
    }
    if one != "g" {
        lOne.text = "M"
    }
    if one != "h" {
        lOne.text = "N"
    }
    if one != "i" {
        lOne.text = "O"
    }
    if one != "j" {
        lOne.text = "P"
    }
    if one != "k" {
        lOne.text = "Q"
    }
    if one != "l" {
        lOne.text = "R"
    }
    if one != "m" {
        lOne.text = "S"
    }
    if one != "n" {
        lOne.text = "T"
    }
    if one != "o" {
        lOne.text = "U"
    }
    if one != "p" {
        lOne.text = "V"
    }
    if one != "q" {
        lOne.text = "W"
    }
    if one != "r" {
        lOne.text = "X"
    }
    if one != "s" {
        lOne.text = "Y"
    }
    if one != "t" {
        lOne.text = "Z"
    }
    if one != "u" {
        lOne.text = "A"
    }
    if one != "v" {
        lOne.text = "B"
    }
    if one != "w" {
        lOne.text = "C"
    }
    if one != "x" {
        lOne.text = "D"
    }
    if one != "y" {
        lOne.text = "E"
    }
    if one != "z" {
        lOne.text = "F"
    } else {
        lOne.text = ""
    }
```

I have two questions about my code. First I would like a more efficient way to write this but, the biggest question I have is when I run it on an iPhone it skips all the way to the last line and outputs that. When it should look at every line any output the correct answer.
By the way if you are wondering this is to make a app that takes words and makes them into code so that without the key you cannot read them.

Comment: You should describe the logic that you are trying to achieve. It appears that your code makes multiple assignments, all of which are useless, because the final `if` statement unconditionally writes over whatever has been written into `lOne.text`.

Comment: you should actually do 2 things: 1. clean up your "if blocks" one could be != a and != b at the same time, what should happen then? 2. use regex based matching for true/false evaluation

Comment: It looks like you are trying to "map" one character to another. Perhaps you could represent the mapping in a dictionary (something like `["a":"G", "b":"H", …]`), then iterate each character and replace it with the mapped value in the dictionary.